# Hibernate to POJO Generator

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pojo

I was googling for Hibernate to POJO Generator and found this [Hibernate POJO Generator](http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/) .

I downloaded its jar file but couldn't find any way to use it.

I want to generate all Hibernate DAO related classes by giving a DB table schema.

I know that another way is to use eclipse plugin, but I want to generate classes from Hibernate POJO Generator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usage is documented in the Usage Example page :

> HbnPojoGen is not (yet) an eclipse
> plugin.
>
> To use, run the jar file
> provided together with a config file
> which you’ll have to customize to your
> liking as follows:

```
java -jar hbnPojoGen.jar config.xml
```

> The
> configuration file contains everything
> necessary to generate your source
> code.

Answer (score 1):

Example config file can be found on following location

http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/

set correct configuration and run as jar, it will generate the required mapping pojos.

Answer (score 0):

I used [dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) to generate my pojo's from database schema

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this tool via the provided maven plugin